# How to force Tailwind to use mobile classes on a desktop device?

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind CSS. My CSS supports two design sizes:

- mobile (<= 768px)
- desktop (> 768px)

For example, I have css like:

```
<img class="w-16 md:w-32 src="..." />
```

I am building an admin form where the user can fill out form fields (on the left) and then see how it will later be rendered (on the right).

The preview on the right has a Desktop/Mobile toggle. I'm unsure how I can force Tailwind to use mobile classes when the user toggles the preview into "Mobile mode".

The problem is that Tailwind classes (e.g. `w-16 md:w-32`) refer to the size of the viewport. However, in this case, I want to render the mobile classes when the user is on a desktop device.

How can I force Tailwind to use mobile classes when the user presses the "Mobile" toggle (even if they are on Desktop device)?

[image]

Comment: Try to toggle class on a wrapper (let name it `.mobile-view`) and use classes like `w-16 [.mobile-view_&]:w-16 md:w-32`

Comment: Hi Ihar, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I would have to add `[.mobile-view_&]` for every element inside the Preview Page (~300 className definitions). I wonder if there is a solution that doesn't leave such a big footprint?

Comment: I think, `<iframe>` tag will do the trick. But it depends on your task - is it appropriate for you or not

Comment: An iframe will work! Thanks Ihar!

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to this, but I was looking for a similar solution to this and an iFrame wouldn't work in my implementation.

Found a Tailwind package that did exactly what I was looking for, but still requires some editing of the queries you're using. The package is tailwindcss-container-queries: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-container-queries

On your preview container, add a class for @container

Then search and replace your codebase for sm:, md: etc. and replace them with @sm: and @md:

This should resize based on the container instead of the viewport.